# Setting order of features to be run

Tags: javascript, cucumberjs

How do you set the order of features to be run in CucumberJS since what happens now is that it tests  my login feature before my registration feature.

I've tried looking for docs on this topic but nothing came out.

Else I'll be using grunt to target the features one by one.

Comment: Why does the order matter? If your scenarios rely on others being run first, then you've got unreliable tests.

You should be able to run each test in any order, and it should still pass.

Comment: @KyleFairns Well I used cucumber with selenium and tried to use it for itegration / UI flow testing where some UI elements only show up after certain actions. Anyway I've moved to another testing framework.